# GStreamer transrating / transcoding to multiple Outputs

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, transcoding

is it possible to transrate / transcode a RTMP or RTP Stream with GStreamer to multiple output streams?

For example:

Input: RTP h264 Stream with 1500 kbits
Outputs:
- RTP h.264 Stream with 1500 kbits
- RTP h.264 Stream with 1000 kbits
- RTP h.264 Stream with 500 kbits

It's important that the output streams are synced.

Thanks for your help.
Jan

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got it myself.
The answer is yes. It can be done with gstreamer.